# Searching specific folder / extension using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I How can I search a specific file using vb.net and store the path in a variable?
For example if I need to know where I have *.abc files in my entire computer, how can this be done?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("c:\")
    Dim files() As FileInfo = di.GetFiles("*.abc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: I tried the code but error says
DirectoryInfo not defined
file info not defined
Also, how can I store the path into a variable

Comment: Both of those types are in System.IO, so you'll need to put a Import statement for System.IO at the top of your code file, maybe add a reference to it if you don't have one already.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) method that has been introduced in .NET 4.0. If not you could use the [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) method but be warned that this method returns an array of strings which represent the matched filenames and it could block for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is awkward, but this seems to work for me before, maybe you can try it

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(txtName.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Match not found")
    Else
        MsgBox("Match found")
End If
```

**Update**

This one works

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\WinVault")
If Not System.IO.File.Exists(txtName.Text & ".wv") Then
     btnSave.Enabled = True
Else
     btnSave.Enabled = False
     'Balloon tip
     bTipControl = txtName
     bTipCaption = "Vault Name"
     bTipText = VAULT_NAME_EXIST
     bTip_Show()
End If
```

And of course, make sure you do import `System.IO` or add reference if not available.